# Crear una tabla en codeigniter

Tags: base-de-datos, codeigniter

Estoy intentando crear una tabla y agregar la estructura en codeigniter 3, de acuerdo a la documentación es de la siguiente forma:

```
$this->load->dbforge();
$fields = array(
            'id' => array(
                'type' => 'INT',
                'constraint' => 5,
                'unsigned' => true,
                'auto_increment' => true
            ),
            'login_oauth_uid' => array(
                'type' => 'VARCHAR',
                'constraint' => '100'
            ),
            'first_name' => array(
                'type' => 'TEXT',
                'null' => true
           ),
            'last_name' => array(
                'type' => 'TEXT',
                'null' => true
            ),
            'email_address' => array(
                'type' => 'TEXT',
                'null' => true
            ),
            'profile_picture' => array(
                'type' => 'BLOB',
                'null' => true
            ),
            'created_at' => array(
                'type' => 'DATETIME',
                'default' => 'current_timestamp()'
            )
        );
        $attributes = array('ENGINE' => 'InnoDB');
        $this->dbforge->create_table('chat_user', true,$attributes);
```

Y me da el siguiente error!:

> An Error Was Encountered Field information is required.

Lo he estado googleando y no logre encontrar información al respecto!

Mi configuración de base de datos es la siguiente:

```
$db['default'] = [
    'dsn' => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'USUARIO',
    'password' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    'database' => 'basededatos',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => false,
    'db_debug' => true,
    //ENVIRONMENT !== 'production',
    'cache_on' => false,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => false,
    'compress' => false,
    'stricton' => false,
    'failover' => [],
    'save_queries' => true,
];
```

Espero que alguien halla tenido el mismo problem!! saludos

Answer (score 0):

Pude encontrar el problema!! estaba en el orden de como asignaba la creación de la base de datos, estaba de forma errónea el orden de los parámetros, seria de la siguiente forma:

```
$this->load->dbforge();
        $fields = array(
            'id' => array(
                'type' => 'INT',
                'constraint' => 5,
                'unsigned' => true,
                'auto_increment' => true
            ),
            'login_oauth_uid' => array(
                'type' => 'VARCHAR',
                'constraint' => '100'
            ),
            'first_name' => array(
                'type' => 'TEXT',
                'null' => true
           ),
            'last_name' => array(
                'type' => 'TEXT',
                'null' => true
            ),
            'email_address' => array(
                'type' => 'TEXT',
                'null' => true
            ),
            'profile_picture' => array(
                'type' => 'BLOB',
                'null' => true
            ),
            'created_at datetime default current_timestamp'
        );
        $this->dbforge->add_key('id',true);
        $this->dbforge->add_field($fields);
        //echo("aqui");
        $attributes = array('ENGINE' => 'InnoDB');
        $this->dbforge->create_table('chat_user', true,$attributes);
```

Tambien el error que encontre que DEFAULT de DATETIME no lo toma asi que hy que agregar toda una linea para que el servidor de base de datos en este caso MYSQL tome crrectamente el default de fecha, de la siguiente manera

> 'created_at datetime default current_timestamp'

Espero que a alguien le sirvA!! saludos